# java.lang.verifyerror with finger print

Tags: android

When i am trying to run my fingerprint authentication app i am getting the following error .

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                      Process: com.example.jagadeesh.fingerprint, PID: 15549
>                                                      java.lang.VerifyError:
>   com/example/jagadeesh/fingerprint/FingerprintActivity
>                                                          at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
>                                                          at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
>                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1064)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2112)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
>                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)